# Oracle CREATE spatial INDEX fails with "too many values"

Tags: oracle, indexing, spatial

When trying to create a spatial index on any SDO_GEOMETRY column (tried from multiple users, including SYS), Oracle fails with this statement:

```
Error at line 1
ORA-29855: error occurred in the execution of ODCIINDEXCREATE routine
ORA-00913: too many values
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_INDEX_METHOD_10I", line 10
```

The database is quite old and creating spatial indexes worked in the past (there are already existing ones that work). A sample of creating an index we used:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_SPATIAL_INDEX (FID NUMBER, GEOM SDO_GEOMETRY); 

INSERT INTO USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA 
VALUES ( 'TEST_SPATIAL_INDEX', 'GEOM',
MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ARRAY(
MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('X', 601000, 619000, 0.1),
MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('Y', 6116000, 6142000, 0.1),
MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('Z', -200, 200, 0.1)),
NULL);
COMMIT;

create index TEST_SPATIAL_INDEX_1 on TEST_SPATIAL_INDEX(GEOM) indextype is mdsys.spatial_index;
```

Running statement:

```
select * from registry$history;
```

returns:

```
25-02-2015 11:54:06.449000                        
APPLY SERVER                        
11.2.0.3 0
Patchset 11.2.0.2.0                                                             
PSU
```

We have two instances (SIDs) under one server (same ORACLE HOME for both) and the other one works. We can't find any visible difference in NLS parameters or Oracle version etc that would set them apart. Any ideas what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be caused by 3rd party backup software - "IBM Tivoli Storage Manager for Databases". There is versions where after online backup database is left in invalid state.
However after restarting oracle service indexes can be created, until backup breaks it again.